# TypeORM - Update with OneToOne join attempts to delete related record

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I have a project which uses TypeORM and I have the following two entities:

```
@Entity("Email")
export class EmailEntity extends BaseEntity implements IEmail {
    @Column({length: 100}) to: string;
    @Column({length: 100}) from: string;
    @Column({length: 255}) subject: string;
    @Column({nullable: true}) html: string;
    @Column({nullable: true}) text: string;
}
```

and

```
@Entity("QueuedEmail")
export class QueuedEmailEntity extends BaseEntity implements IQueuedEmail {
    @OneToOne(email => EmailEntity, {nullable: false, cascadeAll: true})
    @JoinColumn()
    email: EmailEntity;

    @Column() retryCount: number;
    @Column() status: QueuedEmailStatus;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.retryCount = 0;
        this.status = QueuedEmailStatus.QueuedForDispatch;
    }
}
```

`BaseEntity` is an abstract class which has an `id` column with the `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn`.

I have the following code which updates the `status` on a `QueuedEmail`:

```
const queuedEmailEntityArray: QueuedEmailEntity[] =
    await this.queuedEmailRepository.createQueryBuilder("queuedEmail")
        .where("queuedEmail.status = :queuedEmailStatus", {queuedEmailStatus: QueuedEmailStatus.QueuedForDispatch})
        .innerJoinAndSelect("queuedEmail.email", "email")
        .orderBy("queuedEmail.id", "DESC")
        .getMany();

queuedEmailEntityArray.forEach(async (value, index) => {
    let queuedEmailEntity: QueuedEmailEntity = queuedEmailEntityArray.pop();
    queuedEmailEntity.status = QueuedEmailStatus.AttemptingToDispatch;
    await this.queuedEmailRepository.persist(queuedEmailEntity);
});
```

Now, the select correctly loads the array or `QueuedEmailEntity` objects, the `forEach` runs but throws the following exception:

> ```
> query failed: DELETE FROM "Email" WHERE "id"=$1 -- PARAMETERS: [1]
> error during executing query:error: update or delete on table "Email" violates foreign key constraint "fk_d438362cf2adecbcc5b17f45606" on table "QueuedEmail"
> ```

The debug query output shows that TypeORM is updating the `status` field but also updating the `emailId` and then attempting to delete the `EmailEntity` record.

```
UPDATE "QueuedEmail" SET "status"=$1, "emailId"=$2 WHERE "id"=$3 -- PARAMETERS: [1,1,1]
DELETE FROM "Email" WHERE "id"=$1 -- PARAMETERS: [1]
```

I don't understand why TypeORM would need to update the `emailId` field when I have not changed the reference, much less why it would try to delete a record that is still referenced. Can anyone see what is wrong with the above code?